# Primefaces Gmap loading coordinates from database

Tags: jpa, collections, primefaces

I want to load the coordinates from database in a string column and set them in the LatLng object as follows:

```
public void loadAtlas() {
    advancedModel = new DefaultMapModel();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    //get the map coordinates stored in ONE database string column
    for (TbDepUpb codUOR : getItems()) {    
        list.add(codUOR.getCoordenadas());
    }

    //set the coordinates in the list
    for (int i=0; i<list.size();i++) {
        advancedModel.addOverlay(new Marker(new LatLng(valueOf(list.get(i))), "Private Bank"));
    }
```

The problem is LatLng requires a (double, double) values. I used the valueOf as above, but it's a Double.

How can I get the values from the List and separate/set them as LatLng(double, double) requires?

reference: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/gmapHome.jsf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a deep research, I've got satisfied with the following:

Bean method:

```
public void loadAtlas() {
    advancedModel = new DefaultMapModel();

    for (TbDepUpb codUOR : getItems()) {
        advancedModel.addOverlay(new Marker(new LatLng(codUOR.getLatitude(), codUOR.getLongitude()), codUOR.getNome()));

    }
}
```

The JSF (main code):

```
<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" life="6000"/>
    <p:gmap center="-40,-50" zoom="4" type="HYBRID" model="#{tbDepUpbController.advancedModel}" style="width:1100px;height:1200px">
        <p:ajax event="overlaySelect" listener="#{tbDepUpbController.onMarkerSelect}" update="messages"/>
        </p:outputPanel>  
    </p:gmapInfoWindow>  
</p:gmap>
```

Comment: Can you please post the JSF main code and the Bean code completely. I am trying the same with Primefaces 6.1 , JSF Mojarra 2.2.11 on Tomcat 7 with Java 8 and it does not render the polylines / markers.

Comment: Hi Rahul Saini! Sorry, I don't have this codes anymore, but you can post a question with your specific problem, so I'll be glad to help you.

Comment: No worries @jMarcel I now have a complete working example of Polyline render using model from p:gmap and onclick overlaySelect listener to get the Lat Lang coordinates.

Comment: can you send me the main code of selectmarker please? ,i'm stuck on how to show information of a marker when i click on it

Comment: Hi @DetchKing! Sorry, I don't have the code anymore. But you can find about GMap events [clicking here.](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/gmap/event.xhtml)